# Menu attached to mx.controls.PopUpButton never changes

Tags: apache-flex, menu, flex4, popup, flex4.5

I have prepared a very simple test case to demo my problem.

Please just place the 2 files below into a Flash Builder 4.6 project and they will run instantly.

My problem is that the menu attached to my (slightly modified) custom PopUpButton never changes - even though the underlying Array data provider is changed when you click one of the 3 buttons on the right side of it:

[image: screenshot]

**AuxButtonTest.mxml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application 
    xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
    xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
    xmlns:comps="*"
    creationComplete="init()">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.controls.Alert;
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;

            private const XML1:XML = 
                <pref>
                    <aux event="1">One</aux>
                    <aux event="2">Two</aux>
                    <aux event="3">Three</aux>
                    <aux event="4">Four</aux>
                    <aux event="5">Five</aux>
                </pref>;

            private const XML2:XML = 
                <pref>
                    <aux event="1">One</aux>
                    <aux event="2">Two</aux>
                </pref>;

            private const XML3:XML = 
                <pref>
                    <aux event="3">Three</aux>
                </pref>;

            public function init():void {
                _auxBtn.update(XML1.aux);
            }

            //private function handleAuxChosen(event:PrefEvent):void {
                //Alert.show(event.toString());
            //}
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:controlBarContent>
            <!-- commented: aux_chosen="handleAuxChosen(event)" -->
        <comps:AuxButton id="_auxBtn" />
        <s:Button id="_btn1" label="XML 1" click="_auxBtn.update(XML1.aux);" />
        <s:Button id="_btn2" label="XML 2" click="_auxBtn.update(XML2.aux);" />
        <s:Button id="_btn3" label="XML 3" click="_auxBtn.update(XML3.aux);" />
    </s:controlBarContent>
</s:Application>
```

**AuxButton.mxml** (my custom component based on PopUpButton):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:PopUpButton
    xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
    xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
    popUp="{_menu}"
    creationComplete="init(event)">

    <fx:Metadata> 
        <!-- [Event(name="aux_chosen", type="PrefEvent")] -->
    </fx:Metadata>

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.controls.Menu;
            import mx.events.MenuEvent;
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;

            private var _str:String;

            [Bindable]
            private var _data:Array = new Array();

            [Bindable]
            private var _menu:Menu = new Menu();

            private function init(event:FlexEvent):void {
                _menu.dataProvider = _data;
                _menu.addEventListener('itemClick', handleMenu);
                addEventListener('click', handleClick);
            }

            public function update(xlist:XMLList):void {
                _data.length = 0;
                for each (var xml:XML in xlist) {
                    _data.push({label: xml, event: xml.@event});
                }

                label = _data[0].label;
                _str = _data[0].event;

                enabled = true;
            }

            private function handleMenu(event:MenuEvent):void {
                label = event.label;
                _str = event.item.event;
            }           

            private function handleClick(event:MouseEvent):void {
                enabled = false;
                //dispatchEvent(new PrefEvent(PrefEvent.AUX_CHOSEN, _str));
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

</mx:PopUpButton>
```

I've commented my custom event out - it doesn't matter here.

Please just click at the buttons few times and then look at the menu - it always has 5 items and that is wrong.

**UPDATE:** Thank you for the answers - the following code works now for me. I still wonder why isn't ArrayList supported, but ArrayCollection works fine.

[image]

**AuxButtonText.mxml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:PopUpButton
    xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
    xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
    popUp="{_menu}"
    creationComplete="init(event)">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.controls.*;
            import mx.events.*;
            import mx.collections.*;

            private var _str:String;

            [Bindable]
            private var _data:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();
            //private var _data:ArrayList = new ArrayList();

            [Bindable]
            private var _menu:Menu = new Menu();

            private function init(event:FlexEvent):void {
                _menu.dataProvider = _data;
                _menu.addEventListener('itemClick', handleMenu);
                addEventListener('click', handleClick);
            }

            public function update(xlist:XMLList):void {
                _data.removeAll();

                if (xlist == null || xlist.length() == 0) {
                    enabled = false;
                    return;
                }

                for each (var xml:XML in xlist)
                    _data.addItem({label: xml, event: xml.@event});

                label = _data.getItemAt(0).label;
                _str = _data.getItemAt(0).event;

                enabled = true;
            }

            private function handleMenu(event:MenuEvent):void {
                label = event.label;
                _str = event.item.event;
            }           

            private function handleClick(event:MouseEvent):void {
                enabled = false;
                //dispatchEvent(new PrefEvent(PrefEvent.AUX_CHOSEN, _str));
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

</mx:PopUpButton>
```

**AuxButton.mxml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application 
    xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
    xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
    xmlns:comps="*"
    initialize="init()">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            private const XML1:XML = 
                <pref>
                    <aux event="1">One</aux>
                    <aux event="2">Two</aux>
                    <aux event="3">Three</aux>
                    <aux event="4">Four</aux>
                    <aux event="5">Five</aux>
                </pref>;

            private const XML2:XML = 
                <pref>
                    <aux event="1">One</aux>
                    <aux event="2">Two</aux>
                </pref>;

            private const XML3:XML = 
                <pref>
                    <aux event="3">Three</aux>
                </pref>;

            private const XML4:XML = 
                <pref>
                </pref>;

            public function init():void {
                _auxBtn.update(XML1.aux);
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:controlBarContent>
        <comps:AuxButton id="_auxBtn" />
        <s:Button id="_btn1" label="XML 1" click="_auxBtn.update(XML1.aux);" />
        <s:Button id="_btn2" label="XML 2" click="_auxBtn.update(XML2.aux);" />
        <s:Button id="_btn3" label="XML 3" click="_auxBtn.update(XML3.aux);" />
        <s:Button id="_btn4" label="LEN=0" click="_auxBtn.update(XML4.aux);" />
        <s:Button id="_btn5" label="NULL" click="_auxBtn.update(null);" />
    </s:controlBarContent>
</s:Application>
```

Comment: +! for a question w/ a clearly defined problem and enough code to help us help you solve the issue.

Comment: Ugh; it's too late to remove my +1.  The code you supplied does not create the screenshot you posted.

Comment: I don't see any changes to the code that would "make it run".  The main application file refers to a PrefEvent in the handler that I had to comment out; and the controlBarContent seems to hide all content; I had to replace that w/ an HGroup.

Comment: The controlBarContent works for me w/o any changes above - I've just tried  the 2 files out with a fresh Flash Builder 4.6 trial install on another (Win XP) PC.

Comment: I guess the question is; what version of the Flex SDK are you using; now which version of Flash Builder are you using.  ( Flex 4.6?  In a mobile project? Or a web project?  Or an AIR Project?)

Comment: Flex 4.6 and web application. Sorry for not mentioning it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrays do not dispatch any events when their content changes. As a rule of thumb: Using `[Bindable]` on an Array and using it as some kind of dataProvider is *usually* a bad idea since adding/removing doesn't dispatch any events and therefore won't be handled by any component.

Instead of `Array` use an `ArrayCollection` which dispatches events of type `CollectionEvent.COLLECTION_CHANGE` whenever its content changes. Most components in the Flex SDK handle those events and update itself accordingly. So, the following code works since assigning a new `source` to the `ArrayCollection` dispatches a `CollectionEvent` which causes the `Menu` to update its menu items.

```
// you don't need [Bindable] on _data
private var _data:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();

public function update(xlist:XMLList):void
{
    var items:Array = [];

    for each (var xml:XML in xlist)
    {
        items.push({label: xml, event: xml.@event});
    }

    _data.source = items;

    if (items.length > 0)
    {
        label = items[0].label;
        _str = items[0].event;
    }

    enabled = true;
}
```

Comment: There is a lot wrong with the theory of your answer.  First off, even if you are using an ArrayCollection, adding or removing items to that collection will not trigger binding.  It will fire off a collectionChange event.  MX List based classes have code built in to respond to that collectionChange event and update the display list accordingly.  I believe in Spark, this code is in the DataGroup.  This approach is a different implementation than how binding works.  Second, your code "_data.source = items" will not trigger binding events because _data is not actually changed; only a property on

Comment: ..the object it points to.  Third, you say it is usually a bad idea to use Bindable on an array.  How come?  I suspect your code does solve the issue; but not because of binding because the list based classes involved respond to the collectionChange event which is fired when you change the source property.

Comment: Thank you, Gerhard - the ArrayCollection works well for me! (Initially I was trying ArrayList myself, but it isn't rendered correctly by mx.controls.Menu for some reason - please see my updated question). Also the items:Array in your suggestion is omittable - I use the ArrayCollection and it works too.

Comment: Flextras was right of course. The code worked but the explanation why it worked oversimplified and wrong. I've updated my answer in order to correct that.

Answer (score 1):

> My problem is that the menu attached to my (slightly modified) custom
>   PopUpButton never changes - even though the underlying Array data
>   provider is changed

This herein lies your problem.  You have no code to change the menu's dataProvider or sync it with your private _data variable.  The _data array does indeed change, but you have not coded any relation between _data and _menu.dataProvider.

The initial value is set in your init method:

```
        private function init(event:FlexEvent):void {
            _menu.dataProvider = _data;
            _menu.addEventListener('itemClick', handleMenu);
            addEventListener('click', handleClick);
        }
```

But, it is never changed as data changes.

I'll do one little side note here to add that your init() method is called on creationComplete.  Which means the component goes through it's full lifecycle once; then you change the dataProvider of the _menu, forcing it go through it's lifecycle again to redraw with the new dataProvider.  This is usually undesirable.  You should read up on the [Flex Component Lifecycle](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf68641-7ff0.html) to understand what events are fired and when.  I would probably recommend setting the dataProvider on initialize, which is caleld after createChildren() is run, but before the children will be sized and measured.

Anyway, a quick fix is to just change the _menu.dataProvider on the fly in your update:

```
        public function update(xlist:XMLList):void {
            _data.length = 0;
            for each (var xml:XML in xlist) {
                _data.push({label: xml, event: xml.@event});
            }

            label = _data[0].label;
            _str = _data[0].event;

            enabled = true;
                        // new code
                        _menu.dataProvider = _data;
        }
```

Comment: This seems to be more like a workaround to me - setting the _menu.dataProvider again and again (when the XML data comes from my server daemon). Why doesn't the _menu detect, that the content of _data has changed?

Comment: @AlexanderFarber I ask you the question "Why would the _menu detect that the content of _data has changed?"  I'm confused as to why you think these two should be related, when you've written no code to actually relate them.  The answer as to why changing one doesn't change both includes details about how variables point to spots in memory; and it would probably take me a couple of hours to write up.